# XHR error (404 not found) loading @angular/core/testing

Tags: testing, angular, jasmine

I am using Angular 2 RC 5 and wanna integrate Jasmine. Whenever I try to import @angular/core/testing I get an 404 http://localhost:3000/@angular/core/testing not found error. I tried to google it and everything but nothing helped.
I followed the official Angular site to set up Jasmine.

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "lite-server-test": "lite-server --config=liteserver-test-config.json",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite-server-test\" "
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

unit-tests.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Ng App Unit Tests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
    <script src="/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>

    <script src="app/1st.spec.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script>

    System.config({
        packages: {
            'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}
        }
    });

    System.import('app/1st.spec')

            .then(window.onload)
            .catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

my test file

```
import { Hero } from './hero';
import {TestBed, addProviders} from "@angular/core/testing";
let service: Hero;
describe('Hero', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
       addProviders([Hero]);
    });

    it('has name', () => {
        let hero: Hero = {id: 1, name: 'Super Cat'};
        expect(hero.name).toEqual('Super Cat');
    });
    it('has id', () => {
        let hero: Hero = {id: 1, name: 'Super Cat'};
        expect(hero.id).toEqual(1);
    });
    it('inject', () => {
        expect(service.id).toBeNull();
    });
});
```

Without using /core/testing it works fine.

[system.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/785MX.png)

Comment: Did you check you had the folder core/testing in your node_modules ? I have the same packages in RC5 and I can Import from angular/core/testing without any issue.

Comment: Yes it's there, so it's quite strange and I tried to create a new project from scratch and it still has the same error.

Comment: Maybe the problem is coming from systemJS, but it's weird because if you took the Angular2 SystemJS config, it should be working fine by itself.
Can you import other @angular files such as "import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';" ?
What is in your wwwroot node_modules folder ?

Comment: Importing injectable from @angular/core works fine. What do you mean by wwwroot?

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET Core to handle the server side, and it's my folder where  all static files, scripts, images should be placed along with HTML files, according to ASP.NET.
Basically, you are using NPM to download the packages such as Angular2, and you then use either Gulp or manage it in TypeScript config to manage the .js output to your application, and there you use SystemJS to map the files to your application.

In my case, it's the wwwroot folder where I copy all of my needed files along with the specific node_modules I need.

Comment: If a basic @angular/core import works, my best guess would be that your SystemJS doesn't map correctly the files, or the files are simply not there.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'll try to look around my SystemJS hope I can get it work.

Comment: If you could edit your post and add a picture with your project architecture, it would be helpful to detect the exact cause of the problem.

Comment: I added a link with the snapshot of my project architecture

Comment: So actually it's quite different in your case, you don't work on source files that you serve to a static folder like I do.
Can you show your system.js code ? I believe the problem is coming from here.

Comment: Ok I added the system.js file. I also observed that if my service that I want to inject uses any directory like @angular/core or anything else it gives also 404 not found error for that specific directory.

Comment: The systemJS file seems correct too, so either you did not download the latests node_module packages, which might be the reason why you can't import those files if they don't exist in your node_modules, or the problem is coming from somewhere else